# Allow only US users to visit site

Tags: apache, .htaccess

What is the best .htaccess configuration to allow only US users to visit a site?

I can't seem to find a definitive answer that covers all IPV4 and IPV6 users.

Comment: Have you  looked into GeoIP?

Comment: I will research it more, thank you. I was hoping for a simple .htaccess allow or something more elegant like that, if there is such a thing.

Comment: GeoIP should give you a lot of flexibility for allowing/denying per country.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to install `mod_geoip`

On Debian:

```
apt-get install libapache2-mod-geoip

edit /etc/apache2/mods-available/geoip.conf
<IfModule mod_geoip.c>
GeoIPEnable On
GeoIPDBFile /usr/share/GeoIP/GeoIP.dat
</IfModule>

/etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

Then you can limit access to visitors except from US with the following lines:

```
 SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE US AllowedCountry

 Deny from all
 Allow from env=AllowedCountry
```

Comment: does this include ipv6 ips?

Comment: According to their FAQ, it does support IPV6 : https://www.maxmind.com/fr/ipv6-information-and-faq

Comment: Where do you add the SetEnvIf GEOIP_COUNTRY_CODE etc etc etc?

Comment: @IRGeekSauce The question asked for `.htaccess` configuration, but it should work in your VirtualHost configuration or in global apache configuration

Answer (score 1):

You don't indicate a reason for the restriction, but in general, there is no way to limit users geographically. Consider as two obvious counter examples, a user connected through a corporate VPN browsing through a US-hosted proxy server, or a US mobile phone being used to access the web while roaming abroad - not to even mention anonymising networks like Tor.

Even worse, unless you specifically disallow Google-like search engine access, readers can view the cached copies of the page contents.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My reason is, for example, to block content posting from abroad on a local classifieds site. I am aware of the potential pitfalls when it comes to anonymized users such as Tor users but, usually the blocking of Russian bots outweighs the headache of several users not being able to take advantage of an small admin feature. Not that the Russian bots wouldn't be able to use US proxies, but it's another step toward a more localized and secure experience

Comment: Then a black hole filter that identifies specific sources as bots would be more directed than trying to use geography as a proxy for all bad people. The solutions posted all look to be intended to provide the opposite - identify the visitor to allow geographic profiling, the more inclusive the better.

Comment: I'm sorry, botnets was a bad example. The irrelevancy of global users to a local zipcode-based classifieds site is the proper reason in my example